# Spring SQS Message Handler - add custom message attributes to existing message before sending it to Dead-Letter-Queue

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aspect, sqslistener

Currently, the messages on source queue are sent to dead-letter-queue on every exception. My goal is to add custom attributes to the failed message so that engineers have more information about failure when they monitor the dead-letter-queue.

When I tried to add attributes to existing message, I receive an  **java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException** exception.

Here is the aspect code where I add message attributes to existing message. I am using custom aspect which is triggered before sending the message with AmazonSQSClient.

```
@Before(value = "execution(* com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQS*Client.sendMessage*(com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.SendMessageRequest,..)) && args(request,..)",
        argNames = "request")
public void before(SendMessageRequest request) {
   
    Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> messageAttributes = request.getMessageAttributes();
    if (messageAttributes == null) return;
    messageAttributes.put("MoveToDlqFlag", createMessageAttribute("true"));
}
```

This is the code where exception happens.

```
@SqsListener(value = {"${sqs.queue.source-queue}"}, deletionPolicy = ON_SUCCESS)
public void handleMessageReceived(String rawMessage, @Header("SenderId") String senderId, @Headers Map<String, Object> header) {
    var orderMessageWrapper = messageWrapperUtil.create(rawMessage, Order.class);
    var order = orderMessageWrapper.getMessage();
    var receiveCount = (Integer) header.get("ApproximateReceiveCount");

    ...
}
```

Is there a way to add message attributes to existing message before sending to dead-letter-queue? Maybe spring provides a configuration where it is possible.

Comment: You wrote: "This is the code where exception happens". Do you mean UsupportedOperationException, or exception, which causes the message to be sent to Dead-Letter Queue?

Comment: Hey @MykhailoSkliar, thank you for your response. The code that is given as "handleMessageReceived" is the SQS listener. If an exception is thrown for a message received from this method, then the message is forwarded to dead-letter-queue by Amazon SQS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `messageAttributes` map throws `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`, then maybe you could try to create a **new mutable map**, which is a copy of **immutable map**:

```
Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> messageAttributes = new HashMap<>(request.getMessageAttributes());
```

and then you can use `setMessageAttributes()` of `SendMessageRequest`

So I hope that this solution would work (unless `setMessageAttributes` doesn't throw `UnsupportedOperationException` too)

```
Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> messageAttributes = request.getMessageAttributes() == null ? new HashMap<>() : new HashMap<>(request.getMessageAttributes());   
messageAttributes.put("MoveToDlqFlag", createMessageAttribute("true"));
request.setMessageAttributes(messageAttributes);
```